# Change posts status to pending based on user role

Tags: php, wordpress

I have members site where users have to pay to subscribe. When user subscribe his role becomes "member" and now can publish to custom post type called "user-profile"

what I want to do is change the status of all published posts to pending in this post type if for example the user role changed to "expired"

I tried this, but doesn't seem to have any effect

```
 function auto_expire_posts(){
    global $wpdb, $wp_roles;
      //get all post ids of published posts.
      $post_ids = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' ");

foreach($post_ids as $id){
$postid =  $id->ID;
if ($_GET['role'] == "expired" ) 
    {
        $profile_post = array();
        $profile_post['ID'] = $postid;
        $profile_post['post_status'] = 'pending';
        // Update the post into the database
         wp_update_post( $profile_post );

       }
}
}
add_action('set_user_role', 'auto_expire_posts');
```

Comment: You need to select the `post_status` column in the query also.

Comment: wordpress membership plugin

Comment: I'm using gravity forms and manage subscriptions manually, I want if I changed role manually to get result

Comment: `SELECT ID, post_status FROM $wpdb->posts`

Comment: @Fred-ii- so it should look something like this:     `$post_ids = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, post_status FROM $wpdb->posts" );`

Comment: along with the `WHERE` clause, yes; give that a whirl.

Comment: You don't have enough information for us.  **how is this code being run**? Also, this will get **ALL POSTS**, not just the posts for the specified author.  Right after the `$post_ids = $wpdb->get_results(...)` line, add `var_dump($post_ids)`.  Are there posts?

Comment: @cale_b what I'm trying to do is to make a function run automatically if a user role change from anything to 'expired', and I want all the published posts of that specific user with role expired to change status to pending. The code above is just a try, it may or may not work for my need that's why I'm asking for different solution.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you're trying to do.  Now, I'm trying to understand the statement "has no effect".  In order to do that, we need to know **how the code you wrote is being triggered / run / called**.  As you don't include any `add_action` or `add_filter` code, and you don't share where this code has been added, it **appears** as though there is nothing causing this code to run (which would explain why it has no effect).

Comment: @cale_b I used action "set_user_role"

Comment: Show the code, please.

Comment: @cale_b I updated the code in my question, thanks for taking the time to look into this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, your function should have **expired all posts**.  Functionally, it works, so when you say "no effect", that is surprising.

Your function **should be modified** per below, in order to be more efficient (you don't need to loop over the posts) and to ensure you only update the relevant posts, as well as ensuring it doesn't throw notices.

Revised code:

```
// This action passes 3 parameters, so let's accept them - $user_id, $new_role, $old_roles
function auto_expire_posts( $user_id, $new_role, $old_roles ) {
    // If the user didn't USED to be a member, then no need to do anything
    if ( ! in_array( 'member', $old_roles ) ) {
        return;
    }

    global $wpdb;

    // Set the array of values to update
    $update = array(
        'post_status' => 'expired'
    );

    // Set the array that defines the "WHERE" clause
    // WHERE is ONLY published posts that are authored by the specified user
    $where = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => $user_id
    );

    // $updated will contain the number of posts changed
    $updated = $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, $update, $where );
}

// Ensure the add_action passes the 3 parameters through (10 is the priority, 3 is the number of parameters)
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'auto_expire_posts', 10, 3 );
```

This is tested, and I have proven that it works.  **However** there are a handful of reasons you may find it does NOT do what you want:

1. This is leveraging the `do_action('set_user_role')` that is core WordPress.  This hook *may not be called* depending on how you are changing the user's role.  This hook **does get called** if you go to the user's profile through the dashboard, change the role, and click "Save User".  **If it doesn't work, be sure to explain exactly how you are changing the roles.**
2. This will not work if the role you are using is not called "member".  Change the code above (where I've used "member") if necessary to match whatever the role is that you are actually using.  **If it doesn't work, be sure to explain exactly the role name you are using.**
3. "expired" is not a post status I am familiar with.  I believe this will suppress the posts from being displayed, but it may not.  **If it doesn't work, be sure to look in the database to see if the post statuses are changing**.
4. If you don't install this function / hook in (one of many) appropriate locations, then it may not get called.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, however, I'm want to use this to change post status to pending, expired is the a user role, so it should take effect if user role changed to expired, I have many other different roles, member, premuim member...etc, so 'expired' role need to be defined in the code

Comment: I end up wrapping it inside `if ( 'expired' == $new_role ) { }` and removed this completely    `if ( ! in_array( 'member', $old_roles ) ) { }`

thanks you