# Change posts status to publish based on user role

Tags: wordpress, publish, roles

I have members site where users have to pay to subscribe. When user subscribe his role becomes "member" and now can publish to custom post type called "activity"

However if his subscription stops he automatically reverts to a standard role. The code works with this article: [Change posts status to pending based on user role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591580/change-posts-status-to-pending-based-on-user-role)

I would like to do the opposite, on the same model as the article above. Namely: if the user buys a subscription again, all his posts will be published.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry, but SO is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist, and what specific problem you need help with. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.